# How to hit Enter in cmd from VBSCript

Tags: vbscript, cmd

Trying to run few Commands from VBScript

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "cmd /c cd C:\Script & lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property"
```

The Second command `lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\LCMBiar_Import.property` requires me to hit enter to complete its execution. Any idea how to do that through VBScript.

Tried giving 
`objShell.Sleep(1000)
objShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")`

but nothing happens. Still waits for manual hit of enter!

Comment: [`objShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx)? You might also want to add a sleep to give it chance to reach the end of it's execution before sending the Enter key.

Comment: tried it doesn't work

Comment: objShell.run command is creating a new cmd window in that it is waiting for an enter.

Comment: It worked!! thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

The solution is:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```